# VSTO custom OfficeVersion property

Tags: vsto

I'm trying to use a custom property in a VSTO add-in project file to ease pain when switching between VMs with different versions of Office installed. Given a PropertyGroup:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug2010|AnyCPU' ">
    <OfficeVersion>14.0</OfficeVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This works:

```
<ProjectProperties HostName="Word" HostPackage="{29A7B9D7-A7F1-4328-8EF0-6B2D1A56B2C1}" OfficeVersion="$(OfficeVersion)" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Word" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/x" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
```

This does not:

```
<ProjectProperties HostName="Word" HostPackage="{29A7B9D7-A7F1-4328-8EF0-6B2D1A56B2C1}" OfficeVersion="$(OfficeVersion)" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Word" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\$(OfficeVersion)\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/x" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
```

The only difference is a literal 14.0 to DebugInfoExeName in the first instance, and a reference to OfficeVersion in the second. Is there a way through this?

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? I am also facing the same issue and currently working around it by manually hard coding the project file to use a particular office version.

Comment: Unfortunately that was the best I could do.